# Nothing is loaded when the hash is empty with hashchange

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I have a question about the `jquery.hashchange.js`.

I get everything to work, my only problem is when there is no hash.
When you first go to the page, it just is: `domain.com/`

But it should act like: `domain.com/#home`

I tried this, but it wont work:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
        var hash = location.hash;

        if(hash = ''){
            hash == '#home';
        }
});
```

Comment: Fix your code (see @JitendraPancholi's answer) then you could still trigger onhashchange handler once declared: `$(window).hashchange(/*...*/).triggerHandler('hashchange')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, this is my solution:

```
if(hash == '#home' || hash == ""){
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

it should be like

```
if(hash == ''){
    hash = '#home';
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution of @jitendra-pancholi, but it won't trigger the events that load with #home to run. Is there another solution?

Comment: @KayLakeman: You question was not clear. you haven't written that what exactly do you wanted to do.